# PHP only displaying single result from database

Tags: php, html, sql

So I've been working on a small system which involves codes which is used for a user to redeem them for some sort of reward.

So far I have this script in PHP and HTML:
http://pastebin.com/UUsEKpev

It's only showing one result which you can see [here](http://bit.ly/PKDZ6i), I want it to display multiple results in a table going down showing all results.

```
<?php

$yn;
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "password") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mcv") or die(mysql_error());

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM Codes")
or die(mysql_error());  

$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
// Print out the contents of the entry 

if ($row['Used'] == 1) {
    $yn = "Yes";
}
else{
    $yn = "No";
}

?>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Minecraft Codes</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    tbody {
        display: table-row-group;
        vertical-align: middle;
        border-color: inherit;
    }

    tr {
        display: table-row;
        vertical-align: inherit;
        border-color: inherit;
    }

    th {
        border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
        padding: 3px;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 20%;
        background-color: #E5EECC;
    }

    table.reference {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
        border-collapse: collapse;
        width: 50%;
    }

    table.reference td {
        border: 1px solid #C3C3C3;
        padding: 3px;
        vertical-align: top;
        width: 20%;
    }

    table, th, td, input, textarea {
        font-size: 100%;
    }

    body, p, h1, h2, h3, h4, table, td, th, ul, ol, textarea, input {
        font-family: verdana,helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <center>
        <br />
        <h1><u>Minecraft Server VIP Codes</u></h1>
        <br />

        <table class="reference">
            <tr>
                <th>Code</th>
              <th>Used?</th>
          </tr>
          <?php echo "<tr><td>".$row['Code']."</td><td>".$yn."</td></tr>"; ?>
        </table>
    </center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It is welcome here to add the code, and even the result in the question, to let it be complete and coherent.

Comment: mysql_fetch_array returns a single ROW of the query's results, not the whole result set.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are only fetching one row:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array( $result );
```

That line fetches the current row of the result set. You want to do that in a loop:

```
$rows = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $rows[] = $row;
}
```

If you can please avoid using the mysql_ functions, they are deprecated, see the giant warning  [here](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php) and [read this](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php)

Comment: ... or display immediately without storing

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="reference">
    <tr>
        <th>Code</th>
        <th>Used?</th>
    </tr>

    <?php while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)): ?>
    <?php 
        if ($row['Used'] == 1) {
            $yn = "Yes";
        }
        else{
            $yn = "No";
        }
    ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['Code']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $yn; ?></td>
    </tr>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
</table>
```

Comment: Didn't know `while(...): ... endwhile;` was a valid syntax. I'm used to curly braces.

Comment: yes! that too exist,, i have re-edited so that others can understand with readability factor as you did. Dont worry we learn step by step and also we didnt started running when born.

Comment: Couldn't get this to work either, the results either come out wrong or the Code row doesn't display.

Answer (score 0):

Well yes, you call mysql_fetch_row() only a single time, thus you only retrieve a single row. You have to wrap that into a loop that is executed as many times as there are rows.

There are millions of examples on the internet that you can learn from...